# Sorting Tables Twice in one Function - Lua

Tags: lua

Want the function to sort the table by HP but if duplicate HPs then sorts by name. When i run this function it just groups the duplicate HPs together in no order by the name.

```
T = { {Name = "Mark", HP = 54, Breed = "Ghost"}, {Name = "Stan", HP = 24, Breed = "Zombie"}, {Name = "Juli", HP = 100, Breed = "Human"}, { HP = 100, Breed = "Human"} }

function(x, y) if x.Name == nil or y.Name == nil then return x.HP < y.HP else return x.Name < y.Name and x.HP < y.HP end end) end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sort func:

```
function(x,y)
    if x.Name == nil or y.Name == nil then
        return x.HP < y.HP
    else
        return x.HP < y.HP or (x.HP == y.HP and x.Name < y.Name)
    end
end
```

Since you always want differing HPs to be the primary sorting order (and name secondary), you want the HP check to come first in the `or` clause so that if it differs it'll skip any other checks and just determine based on HP.